# What wrong mycode in Jade-template?

Tags: pug

I have my code in Jade-template and using each under each in mycode, run , result, what my code wrong?

```
resultA = [{no: 1}, {no: 2}, {no: 3}, {no: 4}]
resultB = [{no: 1, name: 'Solo'}, {no: 4, name: 'Polo'}]

thead
  tr
    th No
    th Name
  tbody
    each dataA in resultA
      td #{dataA.no}

      each dataB in resultB
        if dataB.no == dataA.no
          td #{dataB.name}
        else
          td
```

//my result
//What wrong mycode?

```
No    Name
1     0
2         0
3             0
4                 0
```

//I want to result like this.

```
No    Name
1     Solo     
2     
3
4     Polo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your jade file:

- use a `-` to define a variable
- `tbody` should have the same indent as thead
- you forget the `tr` for the `tbody` loop (looks like you confuse `tr` and `td`)
- you need to add indent for the loop **and** the markup when looping children (2nd loop)

`

```
- resultA = [{no: 1}, {no: 2}, {no: 3}, {no: 4}]
- resultB = [{no: 1, name: 'Solo'}, {no: 4, name: 'Polo'}]

thead
  tr
    th No
    th Name
tbody
  each dataA in resultA
    tr 
      each dataB in resultB
        if dataB.no == dataA.no
          td #{dataB.name}
        else
          td #{dataA.no}
```